# top align minipage in tabular

Tags: tables, minipage

I have one table with 2 minipages. I wish to top align the two minipages.

e.g.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
            1 & 2 \\ \hline
            3 & 4 \\ \hline
            5 & 6 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} &

    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
            7 & 8 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Now the output is as below:

[image]

How can we align the second minipage on top? That means "7 8" line aligned with "1 2" line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you have `minipage` environments encasing `tabular` environments. Here's a solution that dispenses with the minipages and top-aligns two `tabular` environments within a `tabularx` environment.

To avoid overlaps between the `\hline`s drawn by the outer `tabularx` and the inner `tabular` environments, I've omitted some of your `\hline` instructions from the inner environments. If you decide to get rid of the outer `\hline`s, be sure to re-insert the `\hline`s in the inner `tabular`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X@{}X@{}}
  \hline
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|} 
      1 & 2 \\ \hline
      3 & 4 \\ \hline
      5 & 6 
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|} 
      7 & 8 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Next, here's a version with three vertical bars drawn by the outer `tabularx` (far left, middle, and right). To avoid overlap of the vertical lines drawn by the inner and outer table-like environments, it may again be a good idea to omit the first vertical bar from each of the inner tabulars.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{}X|@{}X@{}|}
  \hline
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l|l|} 
      1 & 2 \\ \hline
      3 & 4 \\ \hline
      5 & 6 
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l|l|} 
      7 & 8 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Finally, for the sake of completeness, here's the code that's needed if you wish to use `minipage` environments after all to typeset the preceding example. Note that it's necessary to use the `[t]` position specifier for both minipages *and* both tabulars in order to get the vertical alignment just right. (Not showing a separate screenshot since the result is identical to the one above.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{}X|@{}X@{}|}
    \hline
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l|l|} 
        1 & 2 \\ \hline
        3 & 4 \\ \hline
        5 & 6 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l|l|} 
        7 & 8 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{minipage}\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am extract the simple example from a complicate case, so use minipage here. I will try to remove it. now use tabularx package, it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly your setup, but it works this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,showframe}   %% remove show frame
\begin{document}
\noindent
{\fboxsep0pt
\fboxrule0.4pt
\fbox{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
        \hspace*{0.5\tabcolsep}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|} \hline
            1 & 2 \\ \hline
            3 & 4 \\ \hline
            5 & 6 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \hfil \vrule\hspace{0.5\tabcolsep}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|} \hline
            7 & 8 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}}}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]